# How to Change ListView Font Color?

Tags: android, listview

I want to make an aplication with a white background using a listView for show items.

But, the default font color of android is white so my items are white too, how can I change the font color of my listview?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you cannot change font color of ListView, because ListView does not have text in it. Instead, you can change the items in ListView which is normally provided using an [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

For more about ListView, check out the [Hello ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). Also, you can check out this [ListView example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) which contains a customized BaseAdapter in ApiDemos. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks !! i'm responding just now because i was searching how to implement a custom adapter.

It worked perfectly !! thanks :)